# Nodejs Mongoose Array push is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Books:[{
    book_name:String,
    took_date:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
    }]
```

I would like to add new Book when user take new book.
What I coded is

```
    const promise= User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.user_id,
    req.body,

    {new:true}
);
let  book_name='something came from req.body'+'is added';

promise.then((user)=>{
  if(!user)
    res.json({
      data:'',
      status:res.statusCode,
      message:'User not found',
      error:''
    });

  user.Books.push({book_name: book_name,took_date: Date.now});
```

But when I request this put route from Postman it shows

```
"Books": [
        {
            "_id": "5e504366980c08159c598c6a",
            "book_name": "something came from',
            "took_date": "2020-02-21T20:53:58.012Z"
        }
    ]
```

But on 3T studio it shows like

```
"Books":[]
```

What are my mistakes.
Thank you

Comment: Are you running `.save()` on user before you query in 3T studio?

Comment: i don't see the book saved anywhere here

Comment: I pushed it on promise, isn't it save ?

Comment: User.findByIdAndUpdate() Method is finding and updateing data,There is no problem with updating, just not pushing the new data into  the Books array.

Answer (score 0):

Now I realize what you all saying, I add console log to see the value and yes it is in the memory but not in the db. I added another save&promise and now it works.
Thank you.